# Add a new table row every 24 hours

Tags: php, html, html-table, row

My question is fairly simple as I am quite new to dynamic coding languages.

Basically, I want to add a new table row to my table, every 24 hours. The new table row should be added at 00:00 every day and the table data is going to be a pre-set variable which isn't an issue.

HERE IS THE CODE :

```html
<?php

$test="London"

?>



<table width"100%">

  <tr>
    <th width="30%">From</th>
    <th width="30%">Player</th>  
    <th width="40%">Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $test ?></td>
    <td></br></td>    
    <td></br></td>
  </tr>

 

</table>
```

Comment: If you want it to happen every day at exactly 00:00 you'll need to use a cron job. How you set up the cron job depends on your hosting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Are you using any database?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that although it seems quite complex. Surely there is some way to tell a table to add a new

Comment: @jameswoski there is, but remember that PHP is stateless (unless you provide the state). Each request is essentially fresh. You need to find a place to store what you need (cache, session, DB etc.) and then build what you need each time the page is requested.

Comment: You can use something simpler to store the data, e.g. a file which has a new row added. But we can't give more help unless we know what sort of storage you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on a Unix-based server you'd need to use a tool called `crontab`. In a terminal connected to your server type `crontab -e` and enter:

```
0 0 * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

Then save the file. In this example `script.php` is the file which adds the new row.

The crontab file is structured as follows:

```
minute hour date month day command
```

So in the example this occurs at minute 0, hour 0, every date, month and day.